# Getting registry value Java

Tags: java, registry

I have a little problem with working with registry in Java. I know it is a little bit hard.

But my Q is, if there is any chance how to check, if some value in registry exist.
`eg HKLM\System\Win\Run\ if there is the subkey "avast"`.

Is there any chance how to do it simply in Java without using JMI and without using 3rd package WinRegistry?

Thank you so much. I can not found anything

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java